# how to detect hough lines on holistically nested edged image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, hough-transform

I am trying to get hough lines for document detection with HED (holistically nested edge detection), but not getting correct hough lines for the document detection.

Image with hough lines:
[image: image with hough lines]

Code:

```py
lines = cv2.HoughLines(out,1,np.pi/180,200,np.array([]),0,0)
for line in lines:
    rho=line[0][0]
    theta = line[0][1];
    a = np.cos(theta);
    b = np.sin(theta);
    x0 = a*rho; y0 = b*rho;
    x1 = np.round(x0 + 1000*(-b));
    y1 = np.round(y0 + 1000*(a));
    x2 = np.round(x0 - 1000*(-b));
    y2 = np.round(y0 - 1000*(a));
    cv2.line(original,(int(x1),int(y1)), (int(x2),int(y2)),(0,0,255), 3)
```

Hed image:
[image: hed image]

Original image:
[image: original image]

Comment: Welcome to SO; question has nothing to do with `deep-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed & replaced with `hough-transform` & `opencv`).

Comment: If you're trying to find the contour of the paper, it may be better to use `cv2.Canny()` and find contours with `cv2.findContours()`. Also `cv2.HoughLinesP()` may be better for this situation to detect the 4 sides of the paper. A third approach would be to simply threshold and find contours

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using the following approach if your goal is to detect the white paper region. Here, thresholding on HED image is applied first to generate binary image as well as to reduce noise. Afterwards, applying HoughLinesP on binary HED image lines are detected. Note that parameters (e.g. minLineLength) of HoughLinesP is tuned for this image size.

```
hed_binary = cv2.threshold(hed, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]  # holistically nested edge image is in gray scale
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(hed_binary, rho=1, theta=1*np.pi/180, threshold=2300, minLineLength=1000, maxLineGap=10)
for i in range(lines.shape[0]):
    x1 = lines[i][0][0]
    y1 = lines[i][0][1]
    x2 = lines[i][0][2]
    y2 = lines[i][0][3]

    cv2.line(original, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 2)
```

Output of this approach is:
[image]

---

You can also use the following approach where binary image is generated from gray scale image followd by contours detection.

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7,7), 0)
binary = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
cnts = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnt = None
max_area = x = y = w = h = 0
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > max_area:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        max_area = area
        cnt = c

cv2.drawContours(original, [cnt], 0, (0,  255, 0), 3)
cv2.rectangle(original, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 3)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: How to calculate parameters for each input image?

Comment: Depending on your original image size (3120x4160)  and target document size, empirically determined the value of `minLineLength` that is quite high since we need to suppress small lines. But in case of second approach you don't need any hard threshold.